# What is glide reflection?

Tags: geometry

What is glide reflection. How to find a reflection axis from a translation form, such as 
$F(v)= Av+B$ and $B$ is not zero?

Answer (score 4):

Glide reflection is the composition of a reflection and a translation parallel to the plane of reflection. If you compose the glide reflection operation with itself, you get a pure translation by twice the original translation vector; this is one way to single out what that vector is.